# In Azure Pipeline how can I skip and XML parent element based on a value in the child?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to azure datafactory and am building a pipeline that copies a large xml file from blob storage and updates a table in an SQL db.
Is it possible to skip a parent element from updating to SQL based on a value in the child? The xml structure is fairly straight forward and I know that I could convert it using an xslt but was wondering if it was possible to include this logic directly in the pipeline?

Here is an example of the xml structure:

```
       <parent>
            <child1>1</child1>
            <child2>2</child2>
       </parent>
       <parent>
            <child1></child1>
            <child2>3</child2>
       </parent>
       <parent>
            <child1>2</child1>
            <child2>4</child2>
       </parent>
   </root>
```

Each parent is a line in the table and I do not want to insert lines where child1 is blank.
So in this example the table must only include the first and third parent elements as lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much experimentation I decided to load all the data into the table and then use a data flow after the copy action which uses the alter row function to delete all the unwanted entries. I would have preferred to filter them out from the copy but this solution was easy and is functional.